# Create a new table from the result of multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have three table named 'a_usd', 'a_aud', 'a_gbp' with structure/data like

```
place                           price   top_countries   quick_search
Afghanistan                     0.3003  0               1
Afghanistan Mobile              0.3003  0               1
Afghanistan Mobile AWCC         0.3218  0               0
Afghanistan Mobile Etisalat     0.2789  0               0
Afghanistan Mobile MTN          0.3218  0               0
```

fourth table named all_countries having structure/data like

```
countries_id    country_name    country_code    currency_code
1               Afghanistan     AF              USD
2               Albania         AL              USD
3               Algeria         DZ              DZD
4               American Samoa  AS              USD
```

I need to creat a new table named quick_rate with structure/data like from the above where a_usd.quick_search, a_aud.quick_search and  a_gbp.quick_search == 1

```
rate_id         country_code        currency_code       mobile      land
1               AF                  AUD                 0.1900      0.1900
2               AF                  GBP                 0.1400      0.1400
3               AF                  USD                 0.2200      0.2200
```

The common logic I wish to apply is:

```
SELECT price FROM a_usd WHERE quick_search = 1
SELECT price FROM a_aud WHERE quick_search = 1
SELECT price FROM a_gbp WHERE quick_search = 1
```

so that I will get 2 rows from each query (I need both rows in a single column for quick_rate.mobile, quick_rate.land). The country code is fetched from 'all_countries'

I need a sql/php script to get the required result.

Comment: 'I need a sql/php script to get the required result.' We will not create a script for you. Please try it yourself and when you encounter a problem while trying, please post that specific problem on this site.

Comment: Gentleman, if I was able to get any idea/logic I would have tried. I am totally blank about this and that is why I am asking help. Hope you understand my pathetic condition. Am in the middle of a live project.

Comment: I do not understand what you want to achieve exactly but I think you want to take a look at mysql views. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html

Comment: Please refer the last table, 'quick_rate'. I want a CSV in this structure so that I can import the data to this table.
I will loop through each row from 'all_countries' and get the value of 'country_name' and 'country_code' and match the all_countries.country_name with the a_usd.place.  a_aud.place, a_gbp.place (may be using LIKE) WHERE quick_search = 1.